# How to find consecutive occurrences of data in a row by date?

Tags: sql, sqlite, gaps-and-islands

The problem I am trying to solve is that I need to know how many times EmployeeId + TenantId (1A) has shown up on consecutive runs starting at a given date (the current run). I really only care if its greater than 1.

My app runs on business days and inserts rows. It logs the current run date/time and it also adds the date and time from the last time it ran (retrieved from a different table obviously).

### Table

```sql
CREATE TABLE EmployeeHistory
(
   ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
   CurrentRun TEXT,
   LastRun TEXT,
   EmployeeId TEXT,
   TenantId TEXT
);
```

### Sample Data

```sql
DELETE FROM EmployeeHistory;

INSERT INTO EmployeeHistory ('CurrentRun', 'LastRun', 'EmployeeId', 'TenantId')

VALUES

-- August 19th run
( '2023-08-19 00:00:00.000000', '2023-08-18 00:00:00.000000', '1', 'A' ), -- Consecutive! (Employee exists in August 18th run)
( '2023-08-19 00:00:00.000000', '2023-08-18 00:00:00.000000', '3', 'A' ), -- Should not be included because was not in August 18th run
( '2023-08-19 00:00:00.000000', '2023-08-18 00:00:00.000000', '1', 'B' ), -- Should not be included because was not in August 18th run
( '2023-08-19 00:00:00.000000', '2023-08-18 00:00:00.000000', '2', 'B' ), -- Consecutive! (Employee exists in August 18th run)
( '2023-08-19 00:00:00.000000', '2023-08-18 00:00:00.000000', '4', 'A' ), -- Consecutive! (Employee exists in all runs)
( '2023-08-19 00:00:00.000000', '2023-08-18 00:00:00.000000', '2', 'A' ), -- Consecutive! (Employee exists in August 18th run)

-- August 18th run
( '2023-08-18 00:00:00.000000', '2023-08-17 00:00:00.000000', '1', 'A' ), -- Consecutive (Employee exists in August 19th run)!
( '2023-08-18 00:00:00.000000', '2023-08-17 00:00:00.000000', '2', 'A' ), -- Consecutive (Employee exists in August 19th run)!
( '2023-08-18 00:00:00.000000', '2023-08-17 00:00:00.000000', '2', 'B' ), -- Consecutive (Employee exists in August 19th run)!
( '2023-08-18 00:00:00.000000', '2023-08-17 00:00:00.000000', '4', 'A' ), -- Consecutive! (Employee exists in all runs)

-- August 17th run
( '2023-08-17 00:00:00.000000', '2023-08-17 00:00:00.000000', '3', 'A' ), -- Should not be included because was not in August 18th run
( '2023-08-17 00:00:00.000000', '2023-08-17 00:00:00.000000', '5', 'A' ), -- Should not be included because was not in August 18th run
( '2023-08-17 00:00:00.000000', '2023-08-17 00:00:00.000000', '6', 'A' ), -- Should not be included because was not in August 18th run
( '2023-08-18 00:00:00.000000', '2023-08-17 00:00:00.000000', '4', 'A' ); -- Consecutive! (Employee exists in all runs)
```

Current output :

```
ID  CurrentRun                  LastRun                     EmployeeId  TenantId
1   2023-08-19 00:00:00.000000  2023-08-18 00:00:00.000000  1           A
2   2023-08-19 00:00:00.000000  2023-08-18 00:00:00.000000  3           A
3   2023-08-19 00:00:00.000000  2023-08-18 00:00:00.000000  1           B
4   2023-08-19 00:00:00.000000  2023-08-18 00:00:00.000000  2           B
5   2023-08-19 00:00:00.000000  2023-08-18 00:00:00.000000  4           A
6   2023-08-19 00:00:00.000000  2023-08-18 00:00:00.000000  2           A
7   2023-08-18 00:00:00.000000  2023-08-17 00:00:00.000000  1           A
8   2023-08-18 00:00:00.000000  2023-08-17 00:00:00.000000  2           A
9   2023-08-18 00:00:00.000000  2023-08-17 00:00:00.000000  2           B
10  2023-08-18 00:00:00.000000  2023-08-17 00:00:00.000000  4           A
11  2023-08-17 00:00:00.000000  2023-08-16 00:00:00.000000  3           A
12  2023-08-17 00:00:00.000000  2023-08-16 00:00:00.000000  5           A
13  2023-08-17 00:00:00.000000  2023-08-16 00:00:00.000000  6           A
14  2023-08-18 00:00:00.000000  2023-08-17 00:00:00.000000  4           A
```

I have googled and read a bit about LEAD and LAG but I couldn't figure out how to get back the data I wanted.

One solution in my mind would be to add a column to track consecutive occurrences and simply increment the sum for a given employee based on the previous run. Is that a bad approach?

Comment: Why have you tagged SQLite and T-SQL? SQLite doesn't use the T-SQL dialect.

Comment: Sorry about that, its removed now. @ThomA

Comment: Yes, because I removed them; you need to (re)tag the (R)DBMS you are using.

Comment: I have added SQLite back @ThomA

Comment: what is your expected output ?

Comment: @AmiraBedhiafi Its in the comments in the insert SQL above

Comment: @VictorioBerra while it is not formatted correctly I provided a new answer

Answer (score 0):

You could simply use the `EXISTS` clause; this would give you only those instances where the same EmployeeId+TenantId occured under CurrentRun +/- 1day:

```
select *
from EmployeeHistory A
where exists (
           select 1
           from EmployeeHistory B
           where A.EmployeeId=B.EmployeeId
             and A.TenantId=B.TenantId
             and (date(A.CurrentRun) = date(B.CurrentRun, '+1 day')
                  or 
                  date(A.CurrentRun) = date(B.CurrentRun, '-1 day'))
             )
```

Why do you keep everything in 'TEXT' columns? you might need to adjust for data-type conversions.

Or... if you want to keep all rows in the output, but simply mark the consecutive ones:

```
select A.*
  ,case when 
            date(CurrentRun, '-1 day')=date(LAG(CurrentRun) over (partition by EmployeeId, TenantId order by CurrentRun)) 
         or date(CurrentRun, '+1 day')=date(LEAD(CurrentRun) over (partition by EmployeeId, TenantId order by CurrentRun)) 
     then 1 
     else 0 
   end as Consecutive
from EmployeeHistory A
```

Comment: My real EmployeeIds are not numbers so that one has to be TEST, ass for the dates with SQLIte I read it does not have a datetime column, has that changed?

Comment: Also does this assume the data is already ordered by the dates correctly like in my sample? Should I add some ordering to be safe?

Comment: İf you want the output to be ordered in a particular way, yes, you should add `order by ...`. As for datetime datatype: apologies, I am not familiar with sqlite, you are probably right.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE EmployeeHistory
(
   ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
   CurrentRun TEXT,
   LastRun TEXT,
   EmployeeId TEXT,
   TenantId TEXT
);
```

✓```
INSERT INTO EmployeeHistory ('CurrentRun', 'LastRun', 'EmployeeId', 'TenantId') VALUES
('2023-08-19 00:00:00.000000', '2023-08-18 00:00:00.000000', '1', 'A'),
('2023-08-19 00:00:00.000000', '2023-08-18 00:00:00.000000', '3', 'A'),
('2023-08-19 00:00:00.000000', '2023-08-18 00:00:00.000000', '1', 'B'),
('2023-08-19 00:00:00.000000', '2023-08-18 00:00:00.000000', '2', 'B'),
('2023-08-19 00:00:00.000000', '2023-08-18 00:00:00.000000', '4', 'A'),
('2023-08-19 00:00:00.000000', '2023-08-18 00:00:00.000000', '2', 'A'),
('2023-08-18 00:00:00.000000', '2023-08-17 00:00:00.000000', '1', 'A'),
('2023-08-18 00:00:00.000000', '2023-08-17 00:00:00.000000', '2', 'A'),
('2023-08-18 00:00:00.000000', '2023-08-17 00:00:00.000000', '2', 'B'),
('2023-08-18 00:00:00.000000', '2023-08-17 00:00:00.000000', '4', 'A'),
('2023-08-17 00:00:00.000000', '2023-08-16 00:00:00.000000', '3', 'A'),
('2023-08-17 00:00:00.000000', '2023-08-16 00:00:00.000000', '5', 'A'),
('2023-08-17 00:00:00.000000', '2023-08-16 00:00:00.000000', '6', 'A'),
('2023-08-18 00:00:00.000000', '2023-08-17 00:00:00.000000', '4', 'A');

````
✓``` 
SELECT a.*
FROM EmployeeHistory a
JOIN EmployeeHistory b
  ON a.EmployeeId = b.EmployeeId
  AND a.TenantId = b.TenantId
  AND a.LastRun = b.CurrentRun
WHERE a.CurrentRun >= '2023-08-17 00:00:00.000000' -- Starting date for the runs
ORDER BY a.CurrentRun DESC;
````

| ID | CurrentRun | LastRun | EmployeeId | TenantId |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2023-08-19 00:00:00.000000 | 2023-08-18 00:00:00.000000 | 1 | A |
| 4 | 2023-08-19 00:00:00.000000 | 2023-08-18 00:00:00.000000 | 2 | B |
| 5 | 2023-08-19 00:00:00.000000 | 2023-08-18 00:00:00.000000 | 4 | A |
| 5 | 2023-08-19 00:00:00.000000 | 2023-08-18 00:00:00.000000 | 4 | A |
| 6 | 2023-08-19 00:00:00.000000 | 2023-08-18 00:00:00.000000 | 2 | A |

```
WITH RankedRuns AS (
  SELECT *,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY EmployeeId, TenantId ORDER BY CurrentRun DESC) AS rn
  FROM EmployeeHistory
)
SELECT a.ID, a.CurrentRun, a.LastRun, a.EmployeeId, a.TenantId
FROM RankedRuns a
JOIN RankedRuns b
  ON a.EmployeeId = b.EmployeeId
  AND a.TenantId = b.TenantId
  AND a.LastRun = b.CurrentRun
```

| ID | CurrentRun | LastRun | EmployeeId | TenantId |
| :---|:-----------|:--------|:-----------|:---------|
| 1 | 2023-08-19 00:00:00.000000 | 2023-08-18 00:00:00.000000 | 1 | A |
| 6 | 2023-08-19 00:00:00.000000 | 2023-08-18 00:00:00.000000 | 2 | A |
| 4 | 2023-08-19 00:00:00.000000 | 2023-08-18 00:00:00.000000 | 2 | B |
| 5 | 2023-08-19 00:00:00.000000 | 2023-08-18 00:00:00.000000 | 4 | A |
| 5 | 2023-08-19 00:00:00.000000 | 2023-08-18 00:00:00.000000 | 4 | A |
[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/fsn9mS9-)